# how to use accelerometer at a very low sampling rate in a background service? (to conserve batteries)

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am developing an app that I would like to have constantly monitor accelerometer sensor data, even when the screen is off, but I would also like my battery to last longer than 5 hours :/  The most obvious thing of course is to set the sampling rate very low.  I have tried to register the accelerometer with both SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL and with a microsecond value of 1000000 (once per second) using

```
senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

but the Android OS quickly (after I jiggle the phone for a couple seconds) decides to override these suggested sampling rates and starts sending my app non-stop accelerometer sensor events at about 100/second, even when I turn the screen off.  Needless to say, this is not good for the battery life.

What I have tried for now is a bit of a hack, and I'm wondering if 1. there is a better, Android appoved way to do it, and 2. if what I've done is going to not actually work the way that I want it to.  My current solution is to immediate unregister the accelerometer after the first reading (from within the listener callback), record the time of unregistering and then to have a separate timer loop that re-registers the accelerometer listener after a half-second has passed.  This *seems* to work, but I don't know if it's going to cause problems on some devices, or maybe the registerListener function itself drains batteries on some devices?  Any advice from anybody else who has made a non-battery-draining always-on background accelerometer listener would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**EDIT 9/7/2016:**
The hack that I described above does seem to work and does seem to save significantly on battery, as long as I slow down the sampling speed to about 0.5 or 1.0 seconds.  If I have any more experience, good or bad, with this technique I'll let you all know.  (If it matters, I'm testing this on a Note 4, Android 5.1.1)  (also added a bit more explanatory code up above)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at how it's handled in this project:

https://github.com/alanszlosek/androidstudio-accelerometer-gps/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/alanszlosek/whenmoving/MainService.java

Seems to be using alarms to schedule logging.  Bit of a different situation with even lower sampling frequency, so I'm not sure what method is more efficient.

Would it be possible for you to stick your logger code up on github or somewhere?  I'm trying to do accelerometer tracking for a grant project and having trouble getting the services and wakelocks to play well together.